# How do I solve logic derivations with disjunctions?

Tags: logic

My premise is ((P v R) → S) and the desired conclusion is R-->S. I cannot understand how to get disjunctions out in problems like this.

Comment: A good rule of thumb when your conclusion is a conditional is to assume the antecedent, derive the consequent, then discharge the assumption.

Comment: ^ They probably can't use the Deduction Theorem here, and are required to apply syllogisms to solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidGudeman , that was in fact the first thing i did. I'm not exactly sure what you get out of telling me that its a "simple problem". Writing apple is simple to you now, yet you wouldn't belittle a kid learning how to write by telling him that its a simple word to write. I suggest that rather than commenting useless comment like this you look inward and ask yourself why you feel the need to belittle someone trying to understand something.

Comment: @Bumble thank you! that actually makes a lot of sense. Ill apply that to the rest of the problems

Comment: @MichaelCarey We've just learned this, which is probably why im a little confused by it

Comment: @MichaelCarey, which i did, solved the problem before Michael solved it all out thanks to the comment reminding me about assuming the antecedent.

Comment: @DavidGudeman why have this site in the first place if people can’t ask questions?

Answer (score 2):

You may have to move things around first in order to apply the syllogisms that you have, but this is the idea:

(P ∨ R) → S   ::  1 Premise

(¬ P ∧ ¬ R) ∨ S :: 2 Logical Equivalence + De Morgans

(S ∨ ¬ P ) ∧ (S ∨ ¬ R) :: 3 Distribution Law

(S ∨ ¬ R) :: 4 Simplification

(R → S) :: 5 Logical Equivalence

Note: I skipped over some applications of commutativity laws.

Also, Step (2) and (5) follow from the equivance between p → q and ¬ p ∨ q

If you are skeptical of the equivalence or haven't been taught it. Compare the truth tables of both statements

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks to @Bumble's comment I actually got the solution. Preciate you taking the time to write this out though!

Comment: Of course! I'm glad you solved it! It's good to see multiple versions, and it's best to have solved it yourself without using my posted solution anyways.